# Matlab Function Call From The Script: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

```
  MSIZE=100
  reftype=0
 ident(2,2)=0

fid1= fopen('MSTRPIN.txt','rt');
    if fid1 < 0
        fprintf('error opening file\n');
        return;
    end

fid2= fopen('MYPULDAT.txt','w+t');
    if fid2 < 0
        fprintf('error opening file2\n');
        return;
    end

 PI=4.0*atan(1.0);
V0=2.997925e8;
V02=V0*V0;
EPS=1.0/(V02*4.e-7*PI);
FAC=1./(2.*PI*EPS);
CMTM=2.54E-5; 

for i=1:MSIZE
   for j=1:MSIZE
     ident(i,j)=0.0;
    ident(i,i)=1.0;
  end
end

   line_number = 1;
  oneline{line_number} = fgetl(fid1);
   while ischar(oneline{line_number})
   line_number = line_number + 1;
  oneline{line_number} = fgets(fid1);
  end
  fclose(fid1);
    for i=1:line_number-1
      Data_1(i,1) = sscanf(oneline{i}(1:3),'%f,');
    end

  n    = Data_1(1,1);
  ncdiv= Data_1(2,1);
  w    = Data_1(3,1);
 sep  = Data_1(4,1);
  t    = Data_1(5,1);
  er   = Data_1(6,1);

  w    =w*CMTM;
  sep  =sep*CMTM;
  t    =t*CMTM;

  DELTA=w/double(ncdiv) 

  %%%%%%%%%Without Dielectric*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%%%%%%%%Fill A1%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  dist=0.0;
  for i=1:ncdiv

   A(1,i)=PHI(dist)
   A(i,1)=A(1,i);
  dist=dist+DELTA;
  end
```

The script above is calling PHI(.) function:

```
function  ret= PHI( D )
global FAC ;
global DELTA;
global t;
DOW=2.0*D./DELTA
TOW=4.0*t./DELTA
DOWM=DOW-1.0
DOWP=DOW+1
if(D==0)
ret=FAC*(0.5*log(1.0+TOW*TOW)+TOW*atan(1.0./TOW)) 
else
ret=DOWM*log(DOWM)DOWP*log(DOWP)-0.5*DOWM*log(DOWM^2+TOW^2)+
   0.5*DOWP*log(DOWP^2+TOW^2)-TOW*(atan(DOWM/TOW)-atan(DOWP/TOW))
 ret=FAC/2.0
 end
end
```

But when the the script run an error occurs:
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in widesefor (line 62)
    A(1,i)=PHI(dist)

When I assign a value manually to the D input variable in the function no error occurs. What is the reason?

Comment: What value do you give for `D` that works? What does it return?

Comment: a one dimensional double value, return value also one dimensional double.

Comment: the result is:  ret[] , it is dimensionless!

Comment: No No, when D=0.0 ret[] and DOW TOW is dimensionles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHI function, there are global variable declerations: FAC, DELTA , t.

To share these variables with a script file, same variables also must be declared

as "GLOBAL" in the script as well as in the function definition.

In the error situation, DELTA and t is not initialized properly in the function

file because of missing 'GLOBAL' declaration in the script file.